# Using a subquery to JOIN a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an starting table, which comes from a query:

```
CREATE TABLE my_base 
(
    the_id varchar(6) NOT NULL, 
    the_pay int NOT NULL, 
    the_name varchar(10) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO my_base
VALUES ('LMUS01', '2000', 'JOE'), 
       ('LMUS02', '1500', 'JACK')
```

And a debt data "my_table" :

```
CREATE TABLE my_table 
(
    the_debt_id varchar(6) NOT NULL, 
    the_debt_amount int NOT NULL, 
    the_debt_date date NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO my_table
VALUES ('LMUS01', '180', '2/12/2019'), 
       ('LMUS01', '200', '2/11/2019'), 
       ('LMUS01', '300', '2/13/2019'), 
       ('LMUS02', '100', '2/10/2019'), 
       ('LMUS02', '150', '2/12/2019')
```

And the query I want is all records in "my_base" joined to the min value of variable "the_debt_date" from "my_table":

```
'LMUS01','2000','JOE','200','2/11/2019'
'LMUS02','1500','JACK','100','2/10/2019'
```

When I do it one by one just in "my_table" I use this query:

```
SELECT the_debt_amount, the_debt_date FROM my_table 
WHERE the_debt_id = 'LMUS01' 
AND the_debt_date = (select min(the_debt_date) 
FROM my_table WHERE the_debt_id = 'LMUS01')
```

But I want all the records from "my_base". I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM my_base 
LEFT JOIN my_table ON the_debt_id = the_id WHERE the_id = the_debt_id 
AND the_debt_date = (select min(the_debt_date) FROM my_table WHERE the_id = the_debt_id)
```

But it sends an error. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the error it sends?

Comment: You are most likely getting multiple values returned in the subquery.

Comment: Hello @WOUNDEDStevenJones, the error is that multiple values are returned in the subquery.

Comment: Hi @Manu, you have the same condition two times: `ON the_debt_id = the_id WHERE the_id = the_debt_id`

Comment: Hello @VBoka, I see below the solution given by Greg Hauswirth similar to the one I tried. Please, could you tell me where is the error? Thank you.

Comment: Hello @Manu I think all is described in my answer. You have the same condition two times. Remove the part `WHERE the_id = the_debt_id` because you have alerady have `ON the_debt_id = the_id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two records in my_base...

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_base 
LEFT JOIN my_table ON the_debt_id = the_id
WHERE the_id = the_debt_id 
AND the_debt_date = (select min(the_debt_date) 
                     FROM my_table 
                     WHERE the_id = the_debt_id)
```

Displays both records but includes redundant fields. Eliminate the * and include a reference to the specific fields you need.

```
SELECT my_base.the_id 
       , my_base.the_pay 
       , my_base.the_name 
       , my_table.the_debt_amount 
       , my_table.the_debt_date 
FROM my_base 
LEFT JOIN my_table ON the_debt_id = the_id
WHERE the_id = the_debt_id 
AND the_debt_date = (select min(the_debt_date) 
                     FROM my_table 
                     WHERE the_id = the_debt_id)
```

Comment: Hello @Greg Hauswirth, thank you for your proposed solution. It worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Use `distinct on`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (b.the_id) b.*, t.*
FROM my_base b LEFT JOIN
     my_table t
     ON t.the_debt_id = b.the_id 
ORDER BY b.the_id, t.the_debt_date asc;
```

The `WHERE` clause undoes the outer join.  But it is not needed anyway.

Comment: Hello @Gordon Linoff, just a question, does the .* act as a wildcard?. It's interesting to see you used the "order" clause to get the first date (in this case the min date).

Comment: @Manu . . . Yes.  It returns all columns from a particular table.  It is really shorthand.  Usually it is better to list the columns you want, although `*` can be handy in ad hoc queries.

Comment: Hello @Gordon Linoff, thank you very much for the given explanation. Have a great day.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try this, it works for me in postgres

```
SELECT mb.the_id, mb.the_pay, mb.the_name, mt.the_debt_amount, mt.the_debt_date FROM my_base mb
           inner join  my_table mt
           on mb.the_id = mt.the_debt_id
    AND mt.the_debt_date = (select min(the_debt_date)
    FROM my_table WHERE the_debt_id = mt.the_debt_id);
```

Comment: Hello @user2222, why an INNER join and not a LEFT? An intersection is more efficient to filter the "my_table data"?

Comment: By the way @user2222, the proposed query worked fine. Thank you.