# Using a subquery to find rows given a max value of date

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table 
(
    the_debt_id varchar(6) NOT NULL, 
    the_amount int NOT NULL, 
    the_debt_date date NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO my_table
VALUES ('LMUS01', '200', '2/12/2019'), 
       ('LMUS01', '200', '2/11/2019'), 
       ('LMUS01', '300', '2/13/2019'), 
       ('LMUS02', '100', '2/10/2019'), 
       ('LMUS02', '150', '2/12/2019')
```

I want the rows from the max the_date grouped by the_id, in this case:

```
'LMUS01','300','2/13/2019'
'LMUS02','150','2/12/2019'
```

I tried the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table 
WHERE the_debt_date = (SELECT MAX(the_debt_date) 
FROM my_table GROUP BY the_debt_id)
```

But the error I get is "more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression". Please, any help you can give will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Here , in this question, your table my_table does not have a column named "the_debt_id" and "the_debt_date. Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59957170/using-a-subquery-to-join-a-table#comment106034810_59957170 it has.  So with this table you shown here and the query you have given you will not get the error you are describing... Also, you are opening question after question on simmilar or same subject. Why dont you ask what you need in one question here it is max ther it is min and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Postgres, you can use handy extension `distinct on` for this:

```
select distinct on (the_id) * from my_table order by the_id, the_date desc
```

Comment: Hello @GMB, thank you for your proposed solution, I have a question, does the "*" act as a wildcard when used with distinct on? what if I need only certain columns?

Comment: @Manu: `*` is the standard SQL way to say *give me all columns in the table*. You can replace this with the list of columns that you want (which is actually a better practice than using `*`).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM my_table 
WHERE the_debt_date in (SELECT MAX(the_debt_date) 
FROM my_table GROUP BY the_debt_id)
```

Use **in** when subquery returns more then one records. 
Use **=** when you are 101% sure that subquery will always return only one record.

Comment: Hello @Hamid Raza, I tried your proposed solution but it resulted in 3 rows, not 2 as per my question. I share my fiddle [https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f4e22fb27dae25ec9d66aec94600ffff]